# Php extract html body content along with html tags not only plain text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in php. I am trying to extract entire body tag from html using php.

Here the my sample html:

```
<html>
<body >
<p>
  Example html content
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want extract only following contentfrom html content:

```
<p>
  Example html content
</p>
```

Using following I tried solve but it's output only string without html tags:

```
 $dom = new domDocument;
 $dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Example html content</p></body></html>");
 $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
 var_dump($body->textContent); //output:Example html content
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use `$dom->saveHTML($body)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as following:

```
   $dom = new domDocument;
   $dom->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Example html content</p></body></html>");
   $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
   var_dump($dom->savehtml($body));
```

Output should be along with html tags:

```
string(26) "<p>Hello!</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `saveHTML()` instead:

```
echo $body->saveHTML();
```

will output the HTML as you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like php native dom, try to use simple html dom, it is easy and fast. Download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html("<html><body><p>Example html content</p></body></html>");
$data = $html->find('body',0);
```

$data is contain all the body elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $data = "<html><body><p>Example html content</p></body></html>";
 preg_match( '/<body>(.*?)<\/body>/', $data, $match );
 print_r($match[1]);
```

Comment: my god, when you regex lover understand, do not use regex on scraping html data.